# Python BeautifulSoup extract Class Text only if it contains specific text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

is there a way to extract the below class if the whole class text = New

```
 <li class="ClassifiedDetail">New
```

tried:

```
doc.find('li', class_ = 'ClassifiedDetail').attrs['New']
```

maybe something like if class text = New or contains 'New', take it?

Comment: `doc.find('li', class_ = 'ClassifiedDetail', text="New")` may work

Comment: @JoseManueldeFrutos doesn't work, below is the answer why. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** *It is not that clear if you mean class or tag, so I assume you mean the text of a tag*

One approach could be use of `css selectors` and `:-soup-contains()`:

```
soup.select('li.ClassifiedDetail:-soup-contains("New")')
```

Alternativ is using `string=re.compile(), cause` string`or in former versions`text` works only for exact matches of full string:

```
soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'ClassifiedDetail',text=re.compile('New'))
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<li class="ClassifiedDetail">New</li>
<li class="ClassifiedDetail">New York</li>
<li class="ClassifiedDetail">Ne </li>
<li class="ClassifiedDetail">Old</li>
<li class="ClassifiedDetail">knew</li>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for li in soup.select('li.ClassifiedDetail:-soup-contains("New")'):
    print(li.text)
```

#### Output

```
New
New York
```